# Third partial derivative approximations on uniform grid

Tags: numerical-methods, derivative

I have uniform grid and have to calculate third partial derivative approximations at nodes.

[There](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Finite_difference_in_several_variables) I found approximations only for second order.

Could someone point me to or explain a way to build formula for third order partial derivatives.

Particularly, I have to calculate *f<sub>xxx</sub>(x,y)*, *f<sub>xxy</sub>(x,y)*, *f<sub>yyy</sub>(x,y)* and *f<sub>yyx</sub>(x,y)*.

Many thanks.

Comment: One way to do it is by fitting a polynomial to the points surrounding and including those where you want to calculate the derivative. Then obtain the derivative of that approximate polynomial, which will be given in terms of the values of the original function in those points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that f[i,j] is the value at node (i,j), and h is the size of space step. You already know how to calculate second order derivatives of f, for example

```
fxx[i,j] = (f[i+1,j]-2*f[i,j]+f[i-1,j])/h^2
fyy[i,j] = (f[i,j+1]-2*f[i,j]+f[i,j-1])/h^2
fxy[i,j] = (f[i+1,j+1]-f[i+1,j-1]-f[i-1,j+1]+f[i-1,j-1])/h^2
```

These are of second degree of accuracy, that is the error is about h<sup>2</sup>. In order to maintain this accuracy, take one more derivative using the symmetric difference rule, like

```
gx[i,j] = (g[i+1,j]-g[i-1,j])/(2*h)
```

This results in:

```
fxx[i,j] = ((f[i+2,j]-2*f[i+1,j]+f[i,j])-(f[i,j]-2*f[i-1,j]+f[i-2,j]))/(2*h^3)
```

(which can be simplified), and similarly for other derivatives:

```
fxxy[i,j] = ((f[i+1,j+1]-2*f[i,j+1]+f[i-1,j+1])-(f[i+1,j-1]-2*f[i,j-1]+f[i-1,j-1]))/(2*h^3)
```